# Recover files from a tmpfs?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, tmpfs, deleted-files

How do I recover files from a tmpfs?

<sup>[Some people say to use Volatility](https://memoryforensics.blogspot.com/2012/08/recoving-tmpfs-from-memory-with.html), but Python 2 Volatility doesn't have any Linux modules, and I don't see where to do file recovery in [the Python 3 Volatility documentation](https://volatility3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).</sup>

Comment: You might consider the line `There is currently no support for recovering deleted files within tmpfs stores.` in the Volatility documentation.

Comment: @doneal24 Thanks. Are there any other ways to recover files on a tmpfs?